# AngularJS data extracting from web api

Tags: angularjs

i am new and have a question :-)
I have started with angularJS and now in the mid of making SPA that gets data from web api and displays to person. In real it is a movie search app that sends request to omdbapi website and gets back data about the movie title such as: title, year, image, actors etc...
My app can grab and show data but i am stacked at the point when search get's back with more than one result(object). 
if i use http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=Batman with $http, my app will show first movie it finds in DB, but if i use http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman, app will get response from website with 9 results(scope objects) in log console when i check $scope but will not show any. therefore, my question is somewhat theoretical; how to show in the view all those response's.
Sorry i am new to angularJS, just three days checking but this is something i can't find on the net.
my C

```
var app = angular.module('movies', [])
app.controller('startmovie', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.film = "Game";
    $scope.click = function () {
        $http({
            url: 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=' + $scope.film ,
            method: 'GET'
        }).then(function (response) {

            $scope.movie = response.data;
        }, function (response) {
            alert("neuspješno");
        }

               );
    };
});
```

my console log:

Search

```
[Object { Title="Game of Thrones",  Year="2011–",  imdbID="tt0944947",  more...}, Object { Title="The Imitation Game",  Year="2014",  imdbID="tt2084970",  more...}, Object { Title="Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows",  Year="2011",  imdbID="tt1515091",  more...}, 7 more...]
```

0

```
Object { Title="Game of Thrones",  Year="2011–",  imdbID="tt0944947",  more...}
```

1

```
Object { Title="The Imitation Game",  Year="2014",  imdbID="tt2084970",  more...}
```

2

```
Object { Title="Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows",  Year="2011",  imdbID="tt1515091",  more...}
```

3

```
Object { Title="The Game",  Year="1997",  imdbID="tt0119174",  more...}
```

4

```
Object { Title="Ender's Game",  Year="2013",  imdbID="tt1731141",  more...}
```

5

```
Object { Title="Spy Game",  Year="2001",  imdbID="tt0266987",  more...}
```

6

```
Object { Title="The Game Plan",  Year="2007",  imdbID="tt0492956",  more...}
```

7

```
Object { Title="The Crying Game",  Year="1992",  imdbID="tt0104036",  more...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to use data in view you have to put them in $scope first (what you already do )

then you can show "$scope.yourvar" with `{{yourvar}}` in the view. 
ng-repeat is used to iterate over an array ( `$scope.movie.Search` )
a little example :

```
<div ng-controller="startmovie">
  <button ng-click="click()">
    click 
  </button>

  <pre>{{movie}}</pre>
  total movies : {{movie.totalResults}}<br>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="s in movie.Search">
      {{s.Title}} - {{s.Year}}
    </li>
  </ul>       
</div>
```

a working example :
http://plnkr.co/edit/G4OQ9SsWXEfjwQO2cezx?p=preview